# Adding ImageField to model causes exception in django

Tags: python, django

I've already created a basic CMS and my next step is to add image upload functionality. I've added some lines to my models.py and after that my model is not validating because of UnicodeDecodeError:

```
    Unhandled exception in thread started by 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 93, in w
    rapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.
    py", line 101, in inner_run
        self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 310,
     in validate
        num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\validation.py", lin
    e 113, in get_validation_errors
        from django.utils.image import Image
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\image.py", line 154, in 
        Image, _imaging, ImageFile = _detect_image_library()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\image.py", line 134, in _dete
    ct_image_library
        "imported: %s") % err
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 168, in
    __mod__
        return six.text_type(self) % rhs
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 35: ordinal
     not in range(128)
```

Here is my models.py code:

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    ...

    class Photo(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        upload_path = '/'
        photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path)
        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.title
```

I've got Python 2.7.6, Django 1.6.1, MySQL-python-1.2.3.

Does anybody know why the exception occurs?

Comment: it is because there is a non ascii(unicode) character in the image name which can not be decoded by the ascii decoder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem could be that your unicode method is not really returning unicode.

It should be something like

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s' % self.title
```

If you say that this did not fix your error, you are correct. I went looking in django code and saw that the error is generated elsewhere. Still, your unicode methods should return unicode not anything else.

Now about the error:
It is raised where django tries to import your imaging library. From what i see, the error appears when raising error generates an error.

That you cant fix, but what you can do is to check out if you have required imaging libraries installed. The code that fails ( and generates original error ) is:

```
import _imaging as PIL_imaging
```

How you can fix it (most likely) is to remove PIL from your computer (if you even have it) and install PILLOW. If you read through the 1.6 release notes : 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.6/ you can see, that pillow is now the preferred image manipulation library for Django.

Copy from linked page: Pillow  is now the preferred image manipulation library to use with Django. PIL  is pending deprecation (support to be removed in Django 1.8). To upgrade, you should first uninstall PIL, then install Pillow.

Go there, follow instructions for uninstalling PIL and installing PILLOW and try your code again.

**Edit**
You actually do not need to uninstall/remove PIL. Removing it could cause problems with stuff like ubuntu, where PIL is apparently needed for gnome3 desktop...

**/Edit**

Comment: I've tried this solition, but it doesn't help. I think that problem is strictly connected with ImageField. The problem disappears when I comment line with that field

Comment: Changed my answer. hopefully its of more use to you now. If this works out, don't forget to accept the answer, so others may find use in it too.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much, Odif Yltsaeb! It works!

Instruction for newbies like me:

1) Go to https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.3.0 and download proper version of Pillow

2) To your models.py add

```
import PIL.Image as Image
```

Now it should work!

Comment: Great, for the people coming in the future, this worked