# Django ascii/utf-8 encoding error on Windows caused by ImageField

Tags: python, django, encoding

I'm running Django application on Windows.

I noticed that it stopped working after I've had added `ImageField` in one of my models (when I commented this field, application runs).

I've got following error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 35: ordinal not in range(128)

I've tried to set local variables:

```
export LANG='en_US.UTF-8' 
export LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'
export LC_LANG='en_US.UTF-8'
```

But it didn't help...

I tried to change system encoding in `manage.py`

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

but I've got following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 35: invalid start byte
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Is it Python 2.x? Add this line to the beginning of the file.

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
```

or check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21352117/adding-imagefield-to-model-causes-exception-in-django)

Answer (score 0):

There is a few possible solutions I can think of. One, try encoding it in base64 instead of just directly encoding it. You could also try using UTF-16 as your codec and see if that helps.